# Accessing object property on form submit (vanilla javascript)

Tags: javascript, forms

I've decided to go back and relearn vanilla js since I've always relied on jquery.

I wanted to make some simple food order form.

My issue is that on my submit method, the "this" will refer to the form being submitted, rather than my placeOrder object.

When the order is submitted, I wanted to push it to my orders array which is inside cacheDom. Obviously, it can't use a push method on a form object.

can someone offer advice on how to go about this?

```
(function () {

var placeOrder = {
  init: function() {
    this.cacheDom();
    this.bindEvents();
  },
  cacheDom : function() {
    this.orderForm = document.getElementById('place-order-form');
    this.elements = this.orderForm.elements;
    this.orders = [];
  },
  bindEvents: function() {

    if(this.orderForm.addEventListener){
      this.orderForm.addEventListener("submit", this.submitOrder, false);  
    } else if (this.orderForm.attachEvent){
      this.orderForm.attachEvent('onsubmit', this.submitOrder);          
    }
  },

  submitOrder: function(e) {
    // this refers to the form being submitted
    e.preventDefault();
    var elements = this.elements;
    var order = {};

    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
      if (elements[i].tagName !== 'BUTTON') {
        if (elements[i].name === 'name') {
          order.name = elements[i].value;
        } else if (elements[i].name === 'food') {
          order.food = elements[i].value;
        }
      }
    }

    //this.orders.push(order);
    console.log(this);

  }

};

placeOrder.init();


}());
```

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/adeneo/0dqmtja6/1/

Comment: Oh, I see. store this outside of the event listener to keep it's scope outside the form.

passing this as a parameter to the submit method is a little confusing, but it's working, so thanks!